# How do I detect silent install?

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, silent

If an NullSoft Install System installer is launched with the /S switch, how can I detect it from the script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IfSilent

or if you are using the logiclib:

```
${If} ${Silent} ...
```